# Is this empty room at the end of 'Failing Forward' a dead end?

Tags: antichamber

So I have the red gun and I am in a tunnel with a yellow light, and a laser switch with a green locked door far away.

[image: The tunnel]

I walk closer to the locked door. Thanks to incredible timing and agility, I pass through the locked door.

I turn back and have a last look at the system I have just passed.

[image: This is difficult to pass through without a cube]

It seems I am in a room with no obvious hidden door, and really nothing to do.

[image: Is this room a dead end?]

Is this room a dead end?

Comment: Can you please put the name of the room in the question? You can see it by pressing Esc and then checking the map. It would really help with actually finding the room you are talking about

Comment: The room is not on the map as far as I know. When I press Escape, I see the pointer in the Northerm part of the map, but I cannot directly teleport to this room: I have to go through maybe five other puzzles first.

Comment: The start is a room called "Falling forward".

Comment: I assumed that this room was impossible to enter, so I am impressed that you got in there. I thought it was just a joke that one worked so hard to find an empty room that he or she cannot even go in, but wants to explore so bad. But since you made it in, maybe it is just an empty room he has yet to update... or is it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, supposedly the developer put it in so there is a place to add more content.

Comment: You have a source for this?

Comment: I asked him on twitter: https://twitter.com/Demruth/status/298040887592755200