# How do I get past the green door in 'Failing Forward'?

Tags: antichamber

After the room with the two eyes on opposite sides and the disappearing bridge between them, and after the room with elevator that you have to jump on in the middle there is a tunnell with yellow light and a green door thats triggered by a laser, leading into a seemingly empty square white room, but it closes before I get through, how do you get past it? I see no other features, hints?

Comment: Ok, I got past it, but now im in a totally blank room, is there anything to do there?

Comment: You should edit the name of the room where you had the original problem into the question. Also, if you have a different question, ask it as a different question.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. [See the original question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103607/3921), which should be improved so that people find the original question with Google.

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  One is asking how to get to the room, the other is asking what to do once you get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the doors momentum to your advantage, as it's somewhat of a physics puzzle with a bit of reflex testing.

If you go too early, the door will not open completely. If you go too late, the door will **bounce** after reaching it's highest point, and will come down too quickly.

> That said, there's little incentive to go through that door. The room is completely empty... hopefully it'll be filled with something awesome in an update. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> it closes before I get through

There is no real trick: you have to improve your timing and reflexes.

As you can see [in another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103607/3921), I could get past this door.

[image]

Comment: Hmm but is there a faster way to get from the laser to door then to walk straightforward? About timing and reflexes, what is there to time and react on? FWIW I got through it by jumping backwards from the laser.